# Merge sort "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison "

Tags: python, algorithm, mergesort

I want to code merge sort in Python 3.

Here is my code:

```
import math

def Merge(array,start,mid,end):
    n1 = mid - start +1
    n2 = end - mid
    i = 0
    j = 0
    left = [None] * n1
    right = [None] * n2
    inv = 0
    for i in range(0,n1):
        left[i] = array[start + i - 1]
    for j in range(0,n2):
        right[j] = array[mid + j]

    left.append(math.inf)
    right.append(math.inf)
    new_list = []
    for k in range(0,end):
        if left[i] <= right[j]:
            array[k] = left[i]
            i+=1
        elif left[i] > right[j]:
            array[k] = right[j]
            j+=1

def MergeSort(array,start,end):
    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array
    mid = math.ceil((start + end)/2)
    MergeSort(array,start,mid)
    MergeSort(array,mid+start,end)
    Merge(array,start,mid,end)


stuff = [1, -5, 17, 32, 6] 
MergeSort(stuff, 0, len(stuff))
print(stuff)
```

I tested first function(Merge) it works as it should. But I have a problem with the recursion. I cannot figure out where is the problem. The error is "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison".

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code defines two functions and quits without any calls at all.

Comment: Insert this line in your MergeSort function (as the first line) and see for yourself whats going on `print("Start %i End %i" % (start,end))` . This has nothing to do with recursion limit

Comment: Seems `for k in range(0,end): ` should be `for k in range(start,end):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no functional exit from `MergeSort`.  The length of the list never changes, as you pass the entire list on every call.  If you start with 5 elements in the list, then `len(array)` is always 5.  As a result, you get down to the left-hand base item (one element) and continue to hammer on that one element forever.

Try checking the bounds, such as

```
if end - start <= 1:
```

This will at least get you to the next execution problems.

---

See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.  If nothing else, learn to put in useful `print` statements to trace data and control flow.

Comment: Upvoting for the blog post on debugging.

Comment: That blog is a standard "favorite" on Stack Overflow.  I've had it bookmarked for at least a year.